How to add new Microsoft Graph scopes to existing client with existing admin consents
I have a client in Azure which uses Microsoft Graph APIs to access data in multiple other tenants with scope Users.Read. This client has admin consent for this scope from those tenants.
Now I want to add a new scope to this client to use additional APIs for new functionality, let's say I need scope Place.Read. I understand that this scope will not be granted for tenants unless a new admin consent is given to include this scope. But will it work to add this new scope without affecting existing admin consents for Users.Read scope?
How do I add this new scope so that tenant admins who wish to give admin consent to my client for granting also Place.Read may do so; while those who don't do anything still give access to Users.Read scope?
I am not very used to working with Azure AD, the existing setup was made by someone else ages ago, so any step by step help would be great. When I enter the client in Azure, I can see the scope and that it requires admin consent, but I cannot see how to add new requested scopes.

In TenantA I created Microsoft Entra multi-tenant application and granted User.Read permission:

And granted Admin consent and signed in with TenantB Global Admin account:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/adminconsent?client_id=ClientID


Now in TenantB , the Enterprise application is created with  User.Read permission granted:

In TenantA I granted Place.Read.All permission:


Note that: If you add the new scope in the TenantA  (where the app resides) application and want to grant the same scope in other tenant, the other tenant global admin must grant admin consent again in order to reflect the new permissions added to the application. And this will not affect the old permissions granted.

Now to add the Place.Read.All permission in TenantB grant admin consent again either via Portal or by the below URL:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/adminconsent?client_id=ClientID


After refresh, you can see both the permissions granted to the TenantB application:


Thanks for an excellent explanation. This makes sense. What I'm worried about is whether adding a new scope in the "source" tenant (the only one I have admin access to) will somehow void the existing grants for the other tenants that previously granted only the original scope. I know I'm probably just being paranoid, but since my entire system would stop working for all customers if I somehow messed up the admin grants, well ...

If I had access to another tenant I could set up a new application from scratch and test all combinations of adding scopes, using them, granting them etc, but I only have access to the one tenant.

Adding new scope in source tenant will not void any existing grants for other tenants

As mentioned in the answer, the other tenant global admin must grant admin consent again in order to reflect the new permissions added to the application. And this will not affect the old permissions granted

Thanks. What I find confusing is that I don't find any page similar to yours above for tenant A. In Microsoft Entra, when logged into my own tenant where the application resides, I enter "Enterprise applications", find my application, and it looks like the screen you posted from tenant B. There is no "API permissions" menu, and no way to add new permissions, only to handle the admin consent (which handles the grants my application has towards my own tenant).
So I'm probably looking in the wrong place - (wouldn't be the first time I went lost in Entra).

In Enterprise applications there will not be API permissions blade in TenantA also

I found the screen I was looking for, it was hidden under "app registrations" instead of applications. The fact that "app registrations" is where I define what permission my app requests, while "applications" is merely where I handle consent for the permissions defined in "app registrations" is just ... horrible UX by Microsoft.
I will accept your answer. Thanks.
